# Assembly Masm x86 16 bit text mode change color

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

```
mov  byte PTR es:[bx], '*'                    
mov  byte PTR es:[bx+1], 00000111B
```

Why that `00000111B` means - blue on black background

How i can change for yellow text on blue background?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode as usual in assembly, you are working with bits, so everything (including graphics, sounds, etc..) must be in the end encoded as 0 or 1 (group of them). How they have to be encoded depends what HW you are using, and in which way, for example the text-video mode requires different kind of bits wrote at different addresses, than graphics-mode ... none of these information are "guessable", so always search for documentation for particular HW which you want to affect.

Comment: thanks, u just solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Why that 00000111B means - blue on black background

It doesn't! Unless the color/palette registers were changed, the attribute byte 00000111b (07h) means **White**OnBlack.

In an attribute byte the foreground color (FGC) is stored in the low 4 bits and the background color (BGC) is stored in the high 4 bits.

```
    FGC
    vvvv
00000111b
^^^^
 BGC
```

> How i can change for yellow text on blue background?

Knowing how the colors are stored and looking at the table below we get
00011110b (1Eh) for the YellowOnBlue attribute.

```
0000b Black
0001b Blue
0010b Green
0011b Cyan
0100b Red
0101b Magenta
0110b Brown
0111b White
1000b Gray
1001b LightBlue
1010b LightGreen
1011b LightCyan
1100b LightRed
1101b LightMagenta
1110b Yellow
1111b BrightWhite
```