# Background Color to yellow

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

Does anybody know how to change the background color to yellow in assembly language?

```
.model small

.data
.code
Mov ax,@data
Mov da, ax

Mov ax, 0600h
Mov bh, 00h
Mov cx, 0000h
Mov dx ,184fh
In 10h

Mov ax,0600h
Mov bh,?
Mov cl,0 
Mov ch,0
Mov dl,79
Mov dh,23
Int 10h

Mov ah, 4ch
Int 21h

End
```

Comment: Related: [How to change text background color in x86-16 assembly using BIOS int 10h](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73261760) .  Also [Assembly Masm x86 16 bit text mode change color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54256179) shows there is a code for "yellow".